# Преобразовать массивы в JS

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста найти подобие операции в PHP средствами JS.

Вот, что есть в PHP:

Массивы в таком виде:

```
$ar1 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);
```

через операцию:

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b,$c){ return [$a,$b,$c]; }, $ar3,$ar1,$ar2);
```

приводятся к такому виду:

```
$values = array(
 array('Месяц', 'Магазин 1', 'Магазин 2'),
 array('1', 15, 25),
 array('2', 25, 45),
 array('3', 30, 50),
);
```

Как можно это-же сделать в JS?

Comment: если что, там в комментариях к тому ответу, откуда взято это про `array_map` был приведен более элегантный вариант с `... $list`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вот решение подсказанное коллегами из США:

```
var arr1 = ['Shop 1', 15, 25, 30];
var arr2 = ['Shop 2', 25, 45, 50];
var arr3 = ['Month', 1, 2, 3];

var result = arr3.map(function(element, index) {
return [element, arr1[index], arr2[index]];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: И чем же это решения отличается от решения выше?